# SQL Select and find rows that not exists in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with phone numbers.

I want check if there is new rows in addresbook table that not exist in users table.

As I am newbie with SQL, is this query correct?

```
SELECT * 
FROM addressbook
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT Phone1
  FROM users 
  WHERE addressbook.phone = users.phone1
)
```

EDIT: I user MySQL with PHPMyAdmin Interface, sorry for not to specify before

Comment: Take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems OK but I would do it like this.

```
select a.* from addressbook a
left outer join users u on a.phone = u.phone1
where
(u.phone1 is null)
```

This is simpler and probably faster.

Comment: In question there is clearly define, that he/she want to found those addresses which are not exist (by Phone) in User Table.

Comment: @VishalPatel Yes, and this is what my query does.

Comment: my query also dose same. You have used left outer join and I have used `Not In`

Comment: @VishalPatel Yes, that's obvious from the answers we gave.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server your query is

```
SELECT * from addressbook WHERE Phone NOT in (SELECT Phone1 from users)
```

Comment: OP does not want "inner join" but the opposite.

Comment: @peter.petrov what you say?

Comment: "I want check if there is new rows in addresbook table that not exist in users table." He needs left outer join from AddressBook to Users. And your two queries are not logically identical. This is what I say.